# Is there "label wrap on character" option in GeoServer GeoCSS?

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-css-module

In GeoServer (using GeoCSS) I am importing layers which use the symbol `_` to wrap characters in QGIS.

As I searched, technically it is possible to have such option, [TileMill](https://tilemill-project.github.io/tilemill/docs/guides/styling-labels/) uses this code `text-wrap-character: '_';`.

Question is if this option is available in GeoServer? Can I do wrap on character?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think this is currently possible in GeoServer, there is an [autoWrap](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/reference/labeling.html#autowrap) vendor option that allows you to specify a maximum width in pixels for a label but that breaks on white space not a specified character.

It would certainly be possible for you to provide a [new function](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/function.html) or an extension to the existing [autoWrap functionality](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/library/render/src/main/java/org/geotools/renderer/label/LabelSplitter.java#L46)